# Html body is taking some padding from right side in mobile and tablet responsive view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My html page body content is pushing in the left but it is not giving any padding to the body. I designed this website using bootstrap. This was not happened before. Can someone guide me. Thanks

[Here is my link](http://netmahiti.in/netmi/irobot-demo/index.html)

Comment: Could you please post how you tried to fix this and what is not working in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you get similar problem next time just delete elements 1 by 1 to find the problem.

Remove:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px)
.footer-mail-left {
    left: 49px !important;
}
```

`style.css` at line 763

Answer (score 0):

Your main image is 1446px, so when your window is wider, you'll have a margin. `img-responsive` applies `max-width: 100%`. A quick fix would be to give the element `width: 100%`.

However, you shouldn't be using an `img` element in a `p` element, but rather a `background-image` in a `div`. You can maintain aspect ration with the `bottom-padding` technique. Something like the following would work:

```
background: url(images/home-banner.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
padding-bottom: 50% !important;
```

Apply CSS like that to the parent div, and you get the same effect without misusing syntactic markup.

You can then apply this information to the other images in the Meet the Robots section as appropriate.